# How to fill numpy arrays simultaneously using multiple indexes in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists as follows where in each list the first element have `indexes` and the second element has the `value` of each indexes (Note: each element in the list is a numpy array).

```
mylist = [[[1 2 4 5], [0.1 0.7 0.7 0.7]], [[0 3], [0.2 0.4]]]
```

So my final output should be an array like this.

```
[0.2, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7]
```

I know the length of the array prior. So, in the above array the length is 6.

So, I defined a numpy array as follows

```
import numpy as np
np.empty(6, dtype=object)
```

I am wondering if it is possible to fill the numpy array at each iteration simultaneouly without filling each index one by one.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, if I understood the structure of `mylist` correctly:

```py
>>> idcs, vals = np.hstack(mylist)
>>> vals[idcs.argsort()]
array([0.2, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7])
```

**Edit:** As Paul Panzer points out in the comments, the sorting operation is unnecessary. If you're not working with big data sets I doubt you will see a difference, but here is another method that should be linear time:

```py
>>> idcs, vals = np.hstack(mylist)
>>> out = np.zeros(len(idcs))
>>> out[idcs.astype(int)] = vals
>>> out
array([0.2, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7])
```

Though I don't like it as much because of the type conversion.

**Edit:** Another one, without type conversion:

```py
>>> idcs, vals = map(np.hstack, zip(*mylist))
>>> out = np.zeros(len(idcs))
>>> out[idcs] = vals
>>> out
array([0.2, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7])
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for something like this. :)

Comment: This is a really clever answer and a great example of `np.hstack` + `argsort()`

Comment: @PeptideWitch it is also an O(n log n) solution to an O(n) problem.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Fair enough—I've added another solution that should be O(n)

Comment: @Seb you can avoid the (back) type conversion you don't like by not using `hstack` in the first place.

Comment: Btw., sorry for being overly critical. It's not a bad solution overall.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate it! And right you are about that conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some timings for three O(n) solutions. @Seb's `hstack`, a `concatenate` based solution and a simple loop:

[image]

Code to produce the graph:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
import numpy as np

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def loop(L,n):
    out = np.empty(n)
    for idx,data in L:
        out[idx] = data
    return out

@B.add_function()
def concat(L,n):
    idx,data = map(np.concatenate,zip(*L))
    out = np.empty_like(data)
    out[idx] = data
    return out

@B.add_function()
def hstack2(L,n):
    idx,data = map(np.hstack,zip(*L))
    out = np.empty_like(data)
    out[idx] = data
    return out

@B.add_function()
def hstack(L,n):
    idx,data = np.hstack(L)
    out = np.empty_like(data)
    out[idx.astype(int)] = data
    return out


@B.add_arguments('total size')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2,20):
        sz = int(2**exp)
        szs = np.random.randint(1,10,sz)
        SZS = szs.cumsum()
        idx = np.split(np.random.permutation(SZS[-1]),SZS[:-1])
        data = np.arange(1,SZS[-1]+1)*0.1
        yield SZS[-1], MultiArgument([[[i,data[i]] for i in idx],SZS[-1]])

r = B.run()
r.plot()

import pylab
pylab.savefig('unchop.png')
```

Comment: I have to admit, I feel a bit silly because the simple loop didn’t even occur to me

Comment: @Seb Don't beat yourself up over it. We keep getting told don't do loops in numpy. It takes some experience to get a feeling for where the exceptions may lie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the length of the array as your guide to pulling out the correct index:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(6):
    for x in mylist:
        if i in x[0]:
            new_list.append(x[1][i])

new_array = np.asaray(new_list)
```